# Write php script results into a text file

Tags: php, windows, command-line, echo

The php script displays the results on screen, but does not export the results to a text file. Doing `php c:\myscript.php > output.txt` works, but does not contain the line breaks (as opposed to the way it appears on screen).

What I am missing here to export the results to a text file?

The script that works on screen with command line:

```
<?php

$list1 = array('a1', 'a2', 'a3');
$list2 = array('b1', 'b2',);
$list3 = array('c1', 'c2', 'c3');

foreach ($list1 as $i) {
    foreach ($list2 as $j) {
        if ( $j == $i ) { continue; }
        foreach ($list3 as $k) {
            if ( $k == $j ) { continue; }
            if ( $k == $i ) { continue; }
            echo "$i$j$k\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I tried to insert this at the end, but getting error.

```
$sListText = file_get_contents("output.txt");
echo nl2br($sListText);
```

I tried this, getting empty text file:

```
$output = null;
foreach....
file_put_contents("output.txt", $output, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux machine `php myscript.php > output.txt` works fine and with line breaks, you use windows, so you must change

```
echo "$i$j$k\n";
```

to

```
echo "$i$j$k\r\n";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` gets the contents of a file as a string, so its no use if you want to write anything to the file.

```
$file = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
//do your stuff here
fwrite($file, $output);
fclose($file);
```

FYI - this will overwrite any existing data in the output.txt file.

Its also important to note that you actually need to put something in the $output variable, so this line `echo "$i$j$k\n";`, needs to be changed to `$output .= "$i$j$k\n";`

Comment: i tried as suggested but getting error: fclose<> expects parameter 1 to to be resource, null given. (sorry, if i missed an obvious, i am new to this.)

Comment: My bad, fixed, just had the wrong variable name in there.

Comment: works! added the  `$output = null;` on line 2; inserted your suggested 3 lines; changed to your suggested `$output .= "$i$j$k\r\n";`